# Javascript function still runs else statement even though if statement condition is met

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to stop the function after getting negative values for my inputs (unit price and quantity). When my inputs are negative value, the alert box will pop up and the total prices of the each row is still 0 as expected, but for some reason the grand total price(the big gray box at the bottom) still displays the amount. How do I make my grand total price value still 0 after inserting negative values?[image]
Here is my code:

```js
function calculateTotal(){
             let sum = 0;
             const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row1');
             rows.forEach(r => {
             a = Number(r.querySelector('.qty').value);
             b = Number(r.querySelector('.price').value);
             c = a * b;
             sum += c;
                 if(a<0){
                     alert("Negative values not allowed");
                 }
                 else if(b<0){
                     alert("Negative values not allowed");
                 }
                 else{
                     r.querySelector('.total').value = c.toFixed(2);
                     document.querySelector('.grandtotal').value = sum.toFixed(2);
                 }});
           }
```

```css
body{   
    font-family: 'Itim', cursive;
    background-image:url('../images/background.jpg')
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
}

tr,td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.row{
    text-align: center;
    background: skyblue;
}

.row1 td:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: right;
}

.row1:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.row1 select{
    width: 100%;
}

.row2{
    background: skyblue;
}

input{
    width: 96.5%;
}

input td:nth-child(2,3){
    text-align: left;
}

input[type="number"]{
    text-align: right;
}

 input.total:disabled{
    background: silver;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: right;
    color: black;
}

input[type=button]{
    display: block;
    width: 18%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

input.grandtotal{
    background: silver;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    color:black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
            <table>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td><b>No.</b></td>
                    <td><b>Book Tilte</b></td>
                    <td><b>Author</b></td>
                    <td><b>Category</b></td>
                    <td><b>Unit Price</b></td>
                    <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                    <td><b>Total</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="row1">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><select>
                        <option disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type="number" value="0.00" min="0" name="price" class="price"></td>
                     <td><input type="number" value="0" name="qty" class="qty"></td>
                     <td><input class="total" value="0.00" name="total" disabled></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="row1">
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><select>
                          <option disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                          <option value="Business">Business</option>
                          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0.00" min="0" name="price" class="price"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" name="qty" class="qty"></td>
                    <td><input class="total" value="0.00" name="total"  disabled></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="row1">
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><select>
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="Business">Business</option>
                            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0.00" min="0" name="price" class="price"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" name="qty" class="qty"></td>
                    <td><input class="total" value="0.00" name="total"  disabled></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="row1">
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><select>
                             <option disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                             <option value="Business">Business</option>
                             <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                             <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                             <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0.00" min="0" step="any" class="price" name="price"> </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" name="qty" class="qty"></td>
                    <td><input class="total" value="0.00" name="total" disabled></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="row1">
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td><input type="text"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                             <option disabled selected>Please choose the category...</option>
                             <option value="Business">Business</option>
                             <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                             <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                             <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0.00" min="0" step="any" name="price" class="price"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" name="qty" class="qty"></td>
                    <td><input value="0.00" disabled class="total" name="total" ></td>
                </tr>
                  
                <tr class="row2">
                    <td colspan="5"><input type="button" value="Calculate Grand Total Price" onclick="calculateTotal()">
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2"><input class="grandtotal" value="0.00" disabled ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: You're running the condition for each row and never resetting `sum` so even if one row has a negative value, another might not, in which case the total is set with the calculated sum. Validate the inputs **before** adding to `sum`.

Comment: 1) You shouldn't allow the user to fill in a faulty value in the first place. 2) You're doing the check in a for loop, and all the zeroes will trigger the else statement. You could have found this out just by debugging the code with breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even when the values are negative, you are still increasing the sum variable. You need to move it into the else statement:

```
else{
   c=a*b  
   r.querySelector('.total').value = c.toFixed(2);    
   document.querySelector('.grandtotal').value = sum.toFixed(2);
}});
```